# Task scheduler created in C++ could not be started

Tags: c++, scheduler

I created an scheduler in C++.I have set all the parameters and the task is configured to run only when the user is logged on with the user name provided(Done by setting the TASK_FLAG_RUN_ONLY_IF_LOGGED_ON flag).

When I try to run the task I get a status "Could not start". Now suppose I manually edit any property in task property and click on OK the task runs fine.

Note:The manual edit specified may be anything, like just adding a space at the end of the excecutable name or the user name. What may be the problem?

Below is the code i am using:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <ole2.h>
#include <mstask.h>
#include <msterr.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Mstask.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 HRESULT hr = S_OK;
 ITaskScheduler *pITS;

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Call CoInitialize to initialize the COM library and then
 // CoCreateInstance to get the Task Scheduler object.
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
 if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
 {
  hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CTaskScheduler,
   NULL,
  CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
   IID_ITaskScheduler,
   (void **) &pITS);
   if (FAILED(hr))
  {
   CoUninitialize();
   return 1;
   }
  }
    else
 {
  return 1;
 }

 LPCWSTR pwszTaskName;
 ITask *pITask;
  pwszTaskName = L"TestTask";

 hr = pITS->NewWorkItem(pwszTaskName,
  CLSID_CTask,
  IID_ITask,
 (IUnknown**)&pITask);

  if (FAILED(hr))
 {
  wprintf(L"Failed calling ITaskScheduler::NewWorkItem: ");
  wprintf(L"error = 0x%x\n",hr);
  CoUninitialize();
   return 1;
  }


  LPCWSTR pwszApplicationName = L"C:\\windows\\notepad.exe";

  hr = pITask->SetApplicationName(pwszApplicationName);

  if (FAILED(hr))
 {
  wprintf(L"Failed calling ITask::SetApplicationName: ");
  wprintf(L"error = 0x%x\n",hr);
  pITS->Release();
  pITask->Release();
  CoUninitialize();
  return 1;
 }

  pITask->SetAccountInformation(L"USERNAME", NULL);
  pITask->SetFlags(TASK_FLAG_RUN_ONLY_IF_LOGGED_ON);
  pITask->SetWorkingDirectory(L"C:\\windows");


  ITaskTrigger *pITaskTrigger;
  WORD piNewTrigger;
  hr = pITask->CreateTrigger(&piNewTrigger,
                         &pITaskTrigger);
  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
    wprintf(L"Failed calling ITask::CreatTrigger: ");
    wprintf(L"error = 0x%x\n",hr);
    pITask->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
  }

  pITS->AddWorkItem(pwszTaskName, pITask);
  pITS->Release(); // Release sceduler

   hr = pITask->Run();
  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
    wprintf(L"Failed calling ITask::Run, error = 0x%x\n",hr);
    pITask->Release();
   CoUninitialize();
   return 1;
  }

   pITask->Release();      
  CoUninitialize();
    _getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you done no debugging at all?  It seems you are dumping a lot of code on us to debug for you.  You should begin the debugging process yourself.  Debugging.

Comment: I would be willing to debug your wall of code for $500 per 10 minutes.

Comment: I am sorry for the long code. But i thought the code is necessary. The code works fine. I think I am missing some properties for the scheduler. If anybody has faced this problem, Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to test all return values, that could be revealing. I'm mostly suspicious about:

```
 pITask->SetAccountInformation(L"USERNAME", NULL);
 pITask->SetFlags(TASK_FLAG_RUN_ONLY_IF_LOGGED_ON);
```

Readinig http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381276(VS.85).aspx I got the impression that you need to call SetFlags first and then SetAccountInformation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Denny. When I am trying to save the trigger by calling pIPersistFile->Save(NULL, TRUE) method it is throwing an error.

The error is:

unable to establish existance of the account specified task scheduler.

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem on XP: status "Could not start" and all ok after manual editing.
Solution:

- Go to Advanced -> View Log. And see the reason for the fail.
- In my case there was "The attempt to retrieve account information for the specified task failed". So I've just needed to get user name via `GetUserName` and set it via `SetAccountInformation`. Note order of `SetAccountInformation` and `SetFlags` doesn't matter.
- Take a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178691) for other reasons.

May be it will help someone someday.